# How to print a pound signs and a variable

Tags: python, variables, printing

So I need to print how much money money would have in this game I'm making, but it won't work. I've put:

```
print("£" coins)

print("£"coins)

print("£" +coins)

print("£" + coins)

print("£" , coins, )
```

none have worked; mostly errors involving 'str'. A few are:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

and then for

```
print("£" , coins, ),
```

it printed

```
('\xa3', 49)
```

So what I'm asking is how do I print a variable and custom text?

Comment: print("£"+str(coins))

Comment: Try this : print("£%s"%(coins))

Comment: You have multiple problems: 1. You're using 3.x `print` function syntax with 2.x's `print` statement; 2. You don't know how to combine strings and numbers (`str.format`, `%`, `+ str(...)`, ...); and 3. Because you're printing the `repr` of the pound symbol, it doesn't look right. `print "£", coins` would have worked just fine.

Comment: Simple `print "£", coins`

Comment: does print u"\xA3"+str(coins) work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Python 2.x:

```
>>> coins = 2
>>> print '£ %d' % coins
£ 2
>>> print '£ {}'.format(coins)
£ 2
>>> print '£ ' + str(coins)
£ 2
>>> print '£', coins
£ 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> coins = 10
>>> print u'\xa3 %d' %(coins,)
£ 10
```

Comment: You can just do `print '£ %d' % coins`